# How to fix Cannot read property 'cellIndex' of undefined dragging from one jqgrid column to other in free jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid has beforeSelectRow event handler defined as

```
        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
            var 
               colName = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest('td')[0]),
               ....
```

If mouse button is hold down in one jqgrid column, mouse cursor is moved to other column in same row and mouse button is released, exception

Cannot read property 'cellIndex' of undefined Line 566

occurs at line 808

```
               colName = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest('td')[0]),
```

with stack trace below (line numbers from todays jquery.jqgrid.src.js  )

If mouse cursor is moved to other row holding button down, this exception does not occur.

How to fix or diagnose this ?
It looks like `$(e.target).closest('td')[0]`  is undefined on dragging between columns in same row.

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cellIndex' of undefined Line 566 Column 12TypeError: Cannot read property 'cellIndex' of undefined  
  at Object.$.extend.getCellIndex (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid-4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js:566:12)  
  at HTMLTableElement.$grid.jqGrid.beforeSelectRow (http://localhost:52216/admin/Grid/Index/DoklstlG?_user=admin&_company=1:808:38)    
  at HTMLTableElement.$.extend.fullBoolFeedback (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid-4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js:1508:35)  
  at HTMLTableElement.$.extend.feedback (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid-4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js:1533:34)  
  at HTMLTableElement.feedback (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid-4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js:1618:26)  
  at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid-4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js:4283:55)  
  at HTMLTableElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js:4665:9) 
   at HTMLTableElement.elemData.handle (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js:4333:46)
```

**Update**

After adding lines in question razor parser throws syntax error.
I tried to this it using  but error still occurs.

I fixed this by using

```
        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
            var iCol, td=$(e.target).closest('td')[0];
            if ( td  == undefined ) {
                return true;
            }
            iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex(td);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have to change your code a little. You should always test that you call `$.jgrid.getCellIndex` with DOM of `<td>` element and not with some other children of it. The code fragment of typical usage of `$.jgrid.getCellIndex` should be the following:

```
var $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td");
if ($td.length > 0) {
    var iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td);
    ...
}
```

Comment: variable td in `$(td)` is undefined

Comment: Should it be `$(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td")`

Comment: @Andrus: the parameter of `$.jgrid.getCellIndex` have to be DOM of `<td>` or jQuery wrapper of `<td>`. Thus before you call it you have to validate that you call it with really `<td>` element. The expression `$(e.target).closest('td')[0]` could be `undefined` or it could be `<td>` of some internal subtable. So you should use `.closest("tr.jqgrow>td")` first of all. `.closest` can stay on the same element in DOM hierarchy or it could traversing up through its ancestors to the `<td>` of the grid row. I have changes the code to use `e.target` instead of `td` variable to make all more clear.

Comment: After adding this ASP.NET razor parser throws syntax error and I was  unable to fix razor syntax. I updated question with fix which I used. Will this also work?  getCellIndex is used in multiple places. Is it resonable to create safe wrapper to it which returns -1 if column cannot found ?

Comment: @Andrus: I fixed already all places of free jqGrid code so that in makes the tests which I included in my answer. The method `getCellIndex` is **internal method**. I am a little wonder that you use it. I personally you always only `c.cellIndex`. The code of `getCellIndex` is more safe (???). It use additionally `if (jgrid.msie) { return $.inArray(c, c.parentNode.cells); }`. I suppose that it's hack for some very very old version of IE. About your suggestion. Even if `getCellIndex` would return `-1` one have to have `if (iCol < 0) { return; }` in your code. So one have to tests before or after.

Comment: Issue exists using current current code from github .  `getCellIndex` is called from `beforeSelectRow` without parameter check  in all samples.  Where to find sample code which finds clicked column index better way?

Comment: @Andrus: You wrote "`getCellIndex` is called from `beforeSelectRow`", but it can't be correct because the code of callback `beforeSelectRow` is not part of jqGrid, it's your code. jqGrid have `click` event handler on the whole body of the grid. Inside of the event handler it calls `beforeSelectRow`, `onCellSelect`, `setSelection` and it can start cell editing. So the `e.target` can still be not `<td>` element. The `beforeSelectRow` is the callback of the lowest level. It will be called even during editing (cell editing, inline editing). So you should be careful in processing.

Comment: I asked about code in question change. Should this code code still call `getCellIndex` from `beforeSelectRow` handler or should it retrieve `cellIndex` directly from element ? Or is there some other event which can used to start inline editing on single click ? Which is best practice for this ?

Comment: @Andrus: I would just use `var $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td"); if ($td.length > 0) { var iCol = $td[0].cellIndex; }`, but I would test it ones in IE with the lowest version which you support, to be absolutely sure. The `cellIndex` is defined by DOM Level 1 (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-82915075)). So I think the `getCellIndex` is obsolete. I will think about deleting it at all from the internal usage if free jqGrid, but to hold for compatibility with old user's code which uses it.